# Raw filter still converting & to &amp; in the source

Tags: twig, twig-filter

I'm trying to use the raw filter on Twig, but it's still converting `&` to `&amp;` in the source.

so it's outputting `&amp;rsquo;` instead of `&rsquo;`

```
{% if entry.title|last == "s" %}
    {% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ "&rsquo;"  %}
{% else %}
    {% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ "&rsquo;"  ~ "s" %}
{% endif %}
```

```
{% if entry.title|last == "s" %}
    {% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ ("&"|raw) ~ "rsquo;" %}
{% else %}
    {% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ ("&"|raw) ~ "rsquo;" ~ "s" %}
{% endif %}
```

edit: realizing i should have said "possessive" instead of "plural" :)

Comment: SO does not like this title :O. Funny to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter `raw` is meant to output content. You can't store content marked as safe in a variable. This mean you need to add `raw` to your output, not the input

```
{% if entry.title|last == "s" %}
    {% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ "&rsquo;"  %}
{% else %}
    {% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ "&rsquo;"  ~ "s" %}
{% endif %}

{{ pluralLocationName | raw }}
```

---

Same thing applies when you print the variable directly, instead of storing it in a variable. There you would need to wrap the full string in parentheses in order to make this work.

The reason is the that filter will be executed first, thus marking `&ruqou;` as safe, but as soon as you concat the string, it will be marked as unsafe content again.

```
{% if entry.title|last == "s" %}
    {{ (entry.title ~ "&rsquo;")|raw  }}
{% else %}
    {{ (entry.title ~ "&rsquo;"  ~ "s")|raw }}
{% endif %}
```

---

*sidenote* You may want to make your snippet shorter like this

```
{% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ "&rsquo;"  ~ (entry.title|last != 's' ? 's') %}
{{ pluralLocationName | raw }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/8aw3j2/2)

Answer (score 2):

**Twig is auto-escaping the output only** so your code is working as you're expecting it and it's escaped whenever you print the result so you could either

Wrap only the output in `{% autoescape %}`:

```
{% if entry.title|last == "s" %}
    {% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ "&rsquo;"  %}
{% else %}
    {% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ "&rsquo;"  ~ "s" %}
{% endif %}

{% autoescape false %}
  <div>
    {{ pluralLocationName }}
  </div>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Output the `|raw` value:

```
{% if entry.title|last == "s" %}
    {% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ "&rsquo;"  %}
{% else %}
    {% set pluralLocationName  = entry.title ~ "&rsquo;"  ~ "s" %}
{% endif %}

<div>
  {{ pluralLocationName|raw }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Wrapping my {{variable}} in `autoescape` did the trick. Hoping to find a cleaner way than having to wrap this variable every time i use it